# String length finding program. What does the line - printf ("%s %n", str, &l); mean in the following program?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char str[100];
int l;
gets(str);
printf("%s %n",str,&l);
printf("%d",l-1);
return 0;

}
```

This program is for finding the length of a string.

Comment: You need to go through the basics of the language. That line specifically, it is to tell the system what data to display and in what format.

Comment: BTW, the C++ header file should be `<cstdio>`.

Comment: This looks like C code. C and C++ are different languages, don't spam tags. If you use a C++ compiler, change the tag, but don't add both unless **both** languages are definitively involved. Said that: What diod you find out? What is the problem with the `printf` documentation? Finally: **never ever** use `gets`! It has been removed from the standard 6 years ago and was strongly deprecated since 1999 as a severe security risk..

Comment: the key here would be to understand what the %n format specifier does.  If only there were some way to look that up

Comment: Note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE OF %n  format specifier in'**C**' :

**Ques**. What is  %n in c  & what did it do?

**Ans**. 
•  %n is a special format specifier. 
•  It loads the corresponding argument with a value equal to the number of 
  characters that have been printed by printf() before the occurrence of %n.

**Sample**

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
  int a;
  printf("I am shivam %nsharma ", &a);       
  printf("%d", a);
   return 0;
}
```

**output**: `I am shivam sharma 12`

Comment: If you've any doubt regarding string please check it out first to find solution in better wa by yourself.. it is all about exploring yourself and accept challenges..  :)

Comment: afterthat, stackoverflow is there for you :)

Comment: good answer should  always be on top on this plateform.. so that it helps others as well as you.. :)

Answer (score 4):

`%s` says output the string `str` and `%n` says print nothing, rather store the number of characters written so far into the memory address of `l`.

for reference on printf and all `%` specifiers [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)